# Getting unwanted output from MongoDB collation

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, collation, mongo-java-driver

### I'm trying to sort the release versions in form of "a.b.c"

I'm using mongo-java-driver

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I have created the index with collation:

```
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
            "version" : 1
    },
    "name" : "version_1",
    "ns" : "db.sysversion",
    "collation" : {
            "locale" : "en",
            "caseLevel" : false,
            "caseFirst" : "off",
            "strength" : 3,
            "numericOrdering" : true,
            "alternate" : "non-ignorable",
            "maxVariable" : "punct",
            "normalization" : false,
            "backwards" : false,
            "version" : "57.1"
    }
}
```

I have implemented the aggregation query with java driver:

```
Collation collation = Collation.builder().locale("en").numericOrdering(true).build();

ArrayList<Document> response = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<Bson> aggregate = new ArrayList<Bson>(Arrays.asList(
  match(gt("version", "1.9.4")), sort(descending("version")),
  project(fields(include("version"), exclude("_id")))
));

this.database.getCollection(sysversion).aggregate(aggregate).collation(collation).into(response);
```

And I'm returning the list in a document as API response.

```
return new Document("version", response);
```

But the output I'm getting is:

```
{ "version" : [{ "version" : "\u000f\u0003\b\u000f\f\b\u000f\u0003\u0001\t\u0001\t" }, { "version" : "\u000f\u0003\b\u000f\f\b\u000f\u0002\u0001\t\u0001\t" }] }
```

And when I tried the same with Mongo shell I get the following output *(which is correct)*

```
{
  version:[
    {
    "version" : "1.10.1"
    },
    {
    "version" : "1.10.0"
    }
  ]
}
```

What's wrong with my Java code? is it the version or error in code?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try this in your `response.forEach(System.out::println);`: instead of `System.out::println` use `doc -> System.out.println(doc.toJson())`.

Comment: No, This is the API response taken from the postman. So, the issue is not with printing.

Comment: MongoDB stores strings in UTF-8, that incorrect output looks kind of like unicode.

Comment: True @Joe, it is returning Unicode value but I'm getting correct output in shell query. Facing this issue with Mongo-Java-Driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Found the issue**

I debugged the issue found that the collation uses the `normalization` for encoding the query response. And by default, that value is `false`. So, the shell query was returning the correct output.

But In Mongo-java-Driver it was setting `normalization` as `true`(by default).

Updated the builder with normalization as `false` for same:

```
Collation collation = Collation.builder().locale("en").numericOrdering(true).normalization(false).build();
```

```
ArrayList<Document> response = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<Bson> aggregate = new ArrayList<Bson>(Arrays.asList(
  match(gt("version", "1.9.4")), sort(descending("version")),
  project(fields(include("version"), exclude("_id")))
));

this.database.getCollection(sysversion).aggregate(aggregate).collation(collation).into(response);
```

**This fixed my issue.**